# Trouble removing angular2-hotkeys hotkeys with .remove()

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement hotkeys in my angular app using the angular2-hotkeys library.

I can successfully create a new hotkey in a component but when I try removing the hotkey again in onDestroy it stays active.

The hotkey however does get removed from the cheetsheet, it just still reacts to the input.

Here's my code:

```
public hotkeyShiftT: Hotkey | Hotkey[];

constructor(private hotkeysService: HotkeysService) {
    this.hotkeyShiftT = hotkeysService.add(new Hotkey('shift+t', (event: KeyboardEvent): boolean => {
        alert('hotkey2 test was a success');
        return false
    }, undefined, 'this is a test'));
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('onDestroy is called');
    this.hotkeysService.remove(this.hotkeyShiftT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this post would be of any help to you. But i would check if `onDestroy` is called.

I am using `"angular2-hotkeys": "^2.4.0"` and with this version, your code seems OK, i have tested it locally and everything seems fine.